# help with hyperbolic functions like sinh and tanh

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

Show that $\sin^{-1}(\tanh x)=\tan^{-1}(\sinh x)$.
Got a hint that $\sin\theta=\tanh x$ but I still don't know how to proceed...

Comment: Does $\tan hx$ denote $\tan (hx)$ or $(\tan h) \times x$?

Comment: @Paul: Neither. $\tanh x$ denotes the [hyperbolic tangent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) of *x*.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks. I see!

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both to show they share the same derivative. Then, check one value to show equality is met. (if $f'(x)=g'(x)$ on a connected domain then $f(x)=g(x)+c$. You want $c=0$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sin\theta=\tanh x$. $\sin^{-1}(\tanh x)=\sin^{-1}(\sin\theta)=\theta$.

We only need to prove $$\sinh x= \tan \theta. $$ To prove it, by using $\sin\theta=\tanh x$,  it only need to prove that

$$\cos \theta =\frac{1} {\cosh x}.$$

In fact: $$\cos^2 \theta=1-\sin^2 \theta=(1-\sin \theta)(1+\sin \theta)=\frac{4}{(e^x+e^{-x})^2}.$$

Now it is easy to get our conclusion.